# Exist some way to pass custom parameter to short dynamic link on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I know how to pass a custom parameter from a DynamicLink created in FireBase and get it on my app but the problem is that I can only make this work with the large link version, like this:

**https://example.page.link/?link=https://example.com.br/?PARAMETER=VALUE&apn=com.example.br**

The problem is that the link is too large, how can I send CUSTOM parameter with the short version from DynamicLink on Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get it to work if you send a request body instead of URL parameters. [The REST docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) explain how to:

```
{
  "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": string,
    "link": string,
  },
  "suffix": {
    "option": "SHORT" or "UNGUESSABLE"
  }
}
```